# LibreOffice application background is black and cannot be changed

Tags: libreoffice, ubuntu-15.04

Since I updated to Ubuntu 15.04 the application background and the background in the context menus is black in LibreOffice:

[image: Screenshot of problem]

<sup>*[View full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aokk3.png)*</sup>

So far I have not succeeded in turning it back to the system colors.

Steps taken:

- Manually changed the colors in Tools -> Options -> Appearance to white
- Turned off and on Tools -> Options -> Accessibility -> Automatically detect high contrast mode
- sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice* and re-install

None of those steps fixed the problem. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try to rename the LibreOffice User directory when LO is closed: `~/.config/libreoffice/4` to `~/.config/libreoffice/4.old` so LO creates a new config directory on next start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tohuwawohu's suggestion solved the problem:

> Try to rename the LibreOffice User directory when LO is closed: `~/.config/libreoffice/4` to `~/.config/libreoffice/4.old` so LO creates a new config directory on next start.